# Include punctuation in keras tokenizer

Tags: keras, tokenize

Is there any way to include punctuation in *keras tokenizer*?
I would like to have a transformation...

FROM

```
Tomorrow will be cold.
```

TO

```
Index-tomorrow, Index-will,...,Index-point
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is possible if you do some pre-processing on the text.

First you want to make sure that the punctuation is not filtered out by the Tokenizer. You can see from the documentation that the Tokenizer takes a filter argument on initialization. You can replace the default value with the set of characters you would like to filter, and exclude the ones you want to have in your index.

The second part is making sure that the punctuation is recognized as its own token. If you tokenize the example sentence the result would take "cold." as a token instead of "cold" and ".". What you need is a seperator between the word and the punctuation. A naive approach is to replace the punctuation in the text with a space + punctuation.

Following code does what you ask:

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

t = Tokenizer(filters='!"#$%&()*+,-/:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\t\n') # all without .
text = "Tomorrow will be cold."
text = text.replace(".", " .")
t.fit_on_texts([text])
print(t.word_index)
```

-> prints: {'will': 2, 'be': 3, 'cold': 4, 'tomorrow': 1, '.': 5}

The replace logic can be done in a smarter way (eg. with regex if you want to capture all punctuation), but you get the gist.

Comment: Thnak you blackplant. This is a trivial solution that could be fine for me.
I was thinking to  separate the words on text_to_word_sequence (keras tokenizer function) with the regular expression  regex=r'(\w+|[\'.,])'  instead of space.

Answer (score 2):

A general solutions, inspired by the one proposed by [lmartens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5536887/lmartens), using Regex expressions to replace a set of punctuation marks. Here the code:

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
import re

to_exclude = '!"#$%&()*+-/:;<=>@[\\]^_`{|}~\t\n'
to_tokenize = '.,:;!?'
t = Tokenizer(filters=to_exclude) # all without .
text = "Tomorrow, will be. cold?"
text = re.sub(r'(['+to_tokenize+'])', r' \1 ', text)
t.fit_on_texts([text])
print(t.word_index) # {'tomorrow': 1, ',': 2, 'will': 3, 'be': 4, '.': 5, 'cold': 6, '?': 7}
```